# MS SQL Server loading XML Source with multiple elements in database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, database

I'm relatively new to SQL Server, so please bear with me!

I have a XML file with multiple elements that I am trying to load into a database table, see below:

```
<ReportStatus>
  <Change>
  <Signatory>XXX</Signatory>
  <Status>XXX</Status>
  <StatusTime>XXX</StatusTime>
</Change>
<Message>
  <CreationTime>XXX</CreationTime>
  <ID>XXX</ID>
  <Version>0.0.1</Version>
</Message>
<Request>
  <References>
    <Reference>
      <RefId>Reference</RefId>
      <RefValue>XXX</RefValue>
    </Reference>
  </References>
  <RequestNr>XXX</RequestNr>
  <Service>
    <Name>XXX</Name>
    <Type>XXX</Type>
  </Service>
</Request>
```

The flow will only let me load one element at one time, I have tried loading the data into the table as such:

[image]

However, this loads the data into the table in 2 separate records:

[image]

Is there a way to consolidate these 2 elements before placing them into the table so the entire record is loaded as a single record?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

Here's the table with the matching fields:

[image]

Comment: the columns in SQL Table screenshot and elements in the XML do not match. Please post the mapping between these two.

Comment: @SivaSenthil I've updated the post to show the XML fields in the table. Thanks in advance.